# how to check if one file's values contain in another file's value?

Tags: perl

i would like to detect new service by comparing two files value.
first file value :

```
FE_EquipmentConstantsSrv_vvvvv
FE_EquipRoutingSrv_vvvvv
FE_ETA_BETA_vvvvv_FrontEnd_GENERAL
FE_DTS_MTSPACE_vvvvv
FE_DTS_MTSPC_vvvvv
FE_DTS_Transfer_vvvvv
```

second file value:

```
FE_DTS_Transfer_1201.1
FE_ETA_BETA_1451.1_FrontEnd_GENERAL
FE_EquipRoutingSrv_1202.1
FE_EquipmentConstantsSrv_1203.1
FE_MESController_1202.1
FE_DTS_MTSPACE_1301.1
FE_DTS_MTSPC_1201.1
```

in this case, we will ignore version number example 1451.1 ,1202.1,1301.1. we only care alphabet. if second file value doesn't exist in first file, show new service detect by it's value. but my code doesn't check all in once and show value . I also not sure how can i ignore the version number in second file while checking the values.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
        
my $firstFile="servicePattern.txt";
my $secondFile="Pattern1.txt";
if(-f $firstFile){
open(svrPatternFile, $firstFile) or die("Could not open file.");
      
open( my $fh6, '<', $secondFile) or die "Could not open file 'secondFile' $!";
foreach my $theServicePattern (<svrPatternFile>)
{   
    $theServicePattern=~ s/\r|\n|\f//g;   ## remove end of line, white trailing space etc.. 
    my $theServicePatternForDB=$theServicePattern;
foreach my $detectservice(<$fh6>)
{

    $detectservice=~ s/\r|\n|\f//g;
    my ($FE,$processID,$version) = split /_/, $detectservice;
    my ($FE1,$processID1,$version1) = split /_/, $theServicePatternForDB;
    if($processID =~ $processID1 )
        {
            print"no new service detected\n";
        }
        else
            {
                print"new service detected $processID\n";
            }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: strip version (eg. `s/_(\d+\.\d+|vvvvv)(_|$)//`); add file1 values to hash; check existence of file2 values in hash

Comment: Why are you using `threads` ?

Comment: sorry i forget to remove that using threads statement;

Comment: You say you want to ignore the version number, but in the code you check `if($version =~ $version1)`.. Why?

Comment: @HåkonHægland that part is wrong, because i m not sure how to ignore only version number :(

Comment: In the code you also compare only `$processID` (the second field)  for a match.. The `$FE` variable is not compared, right?

Comment: yes only compare start from second value

Comment: So in order to know which field (fields are separated by "_") is the version field, you should check for a `vvvvv` field in the first file ? Because it is not given that the version field is a specific field number. From your input data, it looks like the version field can be field number 3 or field number 4

Comment: for the First file, we also ignore the value vvvvv and in second file we ignore version number. then compare two files value whether all second file values contain in first file value

Comment: @jhnc may i know how to put the first file value into hash and compare with second file? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. I read the IDs from the first file into hash (after deleting the `vvvvv` field), then compare each line in the second file (after deleting the version field) to the hash values of the first file:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
{
    my $ids = read_existing_service_ids();
    my $fn = 'Pattern1.txt';
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/_\d+\.\d+(_?)/$1/;
        $line =~ s/^\s*//;
        $line =~ s/\s*$//;
        if (!exists $ids->{$line}) {
            say "New service detected $line";
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

sub read_existing_service_ids {
    my $fn = 'servicePattern.txt';
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my %ids;
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/_vvvvv(_?)/$1/;
        $line =~ s/^\s*//;
        $line =~ s/\s*$//;
        $ids{$line}++;
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%ids;
}
```

**Output**:

```
New service detected FE_MESController
```